# Using DataFactory to call complex REST services

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm setting up a data factory solution that will read data from one REST service, then POST it to another REST service (after some manipulation).

The target REST service has a data model with nested properties. For example: To enter the name of the caller I have to send:
"caller": {"name": "Croga"}

So I've set up a Copy action that uses a temporary SQL storage as Source and the target REST service as Sink. However.....
When I try to do this using a mapping I would want to do something like:
Name->$['caller'][0]['name']
but a Copy action doesn't allow complex JSON mapping in the target.

So I thought I'd us '{"name": "Croga"}' as source data and simply map
CallerNameString->$['caller']
The Copy action does allow that but, of course, the resulting JSON will be mallformed to:
"caller": "{"name": "Croga"}"
resulting in an error on the call (and rightfully so ;-))

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Not sure I've understood fully but if you have the data staged in SQL, can you not assemble the full POST body there before passing to the Copy activity?

Comment: @JasonWelch; I could but how would I copy it to the REST service then? The REST DataSet only takes fields. And those fields don't accept complex JSON as value.

For now the only option I've found is to read the SQL table, then use a ForEach into an HTTP action. Which is a lot more intricate than I would like :-(

Comment: yes I would read the table with the ready-assembled POST body using a Lookup activity and then ForEach / HTTP over its output ... don't think there's an easier way afaik